# How to count context switches programmatically?

Tags: windows, multithreading

Under windows, is there anyway to programmatically count context switches of the same process? The best thing is a callback that gets called whenever a thread is switched.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a [performance counter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373083%28VS.85%29.aspx) that does the work for you. All you have to do is read its value. You can find a description on how to do it interactively [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938606.aspx), but performance counters can also be consumed using their API.

Comment: @yigal: make sure you understand the cost of using the performance counter though. the data is there anyway but collecting it has a cost, you might not want to always use it. see more data here: (search result)
http://books.google.co.il/books?id=MzU3ms3les4C&pg=PA96&lpg=PA96&dq=windows+counters+performance+overhead&source=bl&ots=OcAWMZ4RJb&sig=f0hyl3IRdfo5UnYtKaAJAFwDhac&hl=iw&ei=cfCbStTUFM7D_gaB4KTEBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3#v=onepage&q=windows%20counters%20performance%20overhead&f=false

Comment: Which is the appropriate counter to use for counting context switches?

Answer (score 2):

Problem with counting your own context switches is that you might be switching contexts while counting them! Worse, your own counting code will subtract from the amount of time your own process has, thus you can execute less within one context cycle.

As "On Freund" (+1) says, use the performance counter instead, which counts contexts at a higher level.