# Context switches of thread (C++ windows)

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

How can I know "Context Switches" count with c++, if I know HANDLE of thread?
[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYDa2.jpg

Answer (score 3):

1. By querying perofrmance counters named `Thread(<process-name>/<thread-number>)/Context Switches/sec` using one of the APIs, e.g. [Accessing Performance Data in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384724%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). More on this: [how programmatically count context switches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357761/how-programmatically-count-context-switches)
2. Using Windows internal [`NtQuerySystemInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API, see [Obtaining number of thread context switches programmatically](http://alax.info/blog/1182) for details/code snippet.

Talking about Process Explorer in particular, my guess would be it's taking data from `NtQuerySystemInformation`.